# MySQL: Trying to connect via Named Pipe but getting "open_basedir restriction in effect"

Tags: php, mysql, windows, named-pipes

I am trying to connect to MySQL via Named Pipe (Windows) but it is not working.

I tried with:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('.','user','password','db',null,'\\\\.\\pipe\\MySQL');
$mysqli = new mysqli('.','user','password','db',null,'\\.\pipe\MySQL');
$mysqli = new mysqli('.','user','password','db',null);
```

But I am getting (with all above):

```
Warning: mysqli_connect(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(\\.\pipe\MySQL)...
```

My PHP.ini file has:

```
[PATH=D:/Storage/Web/Test/site123]
open_basedir = "D:/Storage/Web/Test/site123/;\\.\pipe\MySQL"
```

I can connect via WorkBench using Named Pipe without problems.

UPDATE:

The solution was to change to the following as indirectly recommended by arkascha:

```
open_basedir = "D:/Storage/Web/Test/site123/;//./pipe/MySQL"
```

Comment: I am confused by your settings. First: is that dot (`.`) inside the path meant as "the local directory"? Then I would expect that there must not be a leading slash in front, since then I would expect the path to get interpreted absolut. Second: you mix normal and MS-Windows style directory dividers, _why_? I suggest you stick with the normal forward slash, since it causes much less issues with escaping.

Comment: Thank you :-) It is working now :-) See my update-text above :-)

Comment: OK, fine you got thing working! Just out of curiosity: can you tell us where that socket is located inside the file system now? I am still confused by those leading slashes...

Comment: It is not located inside the file system. Windows does not have a socket as in Linux. I am not an expert here. We have just read a lot of speed recommandations about connecting the site directly to MySQL. And this we can do now on our Windows servers :-)

Comment: @arkascha Bear in mind that on Windows named pipes don't sit among other files; the "." indicates that the pipe is on the local *server*. See [Pipe Names](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365783(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @MattGibson I have next to no experience with MS-Windows based systems. I know that they implemented a lot of stuff different from other systems to make their system incompatible. But that is just my experience from the few times I had to deal with those systems in my job.