# Connect PHP/phpMyAdmin to MySQL/MariaDB via named-pipe when skip-networking is enabled on Windows

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Apache 2.4, PHP and MySQL or MariaDB Server are all running under **Windows 10**. phpMyAdmin is used in this environment.

my.ini has the configuration options `skip-networking` and `enable-named-pipe` set. So there is no way to connect via network.

HeidiSQL is connecting well using this configuration using `.` as hostname.

What options may be used for phpMyAdmin, to make him connect? I tried `'.'`, `'localhost'`, `''` and `null`. I also tried the options of my related posts.

How is this done using mysql::real_connect in PHP itself (which phpMyAdmin uses)? I think the [docu](https://www.php.net/manual/de/mysqli.real-connect.php) is unclear for the `socket` parameter.

Related on stackoverflow:

- [PhpMyAdmin connect protocol PIPE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35094453/phpmyadmin-connect-protocol-pipe)
- [MySQL: Trying to connect via Named Pipe but getting "open_basedir restriction in effect"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35189162/mysql-trying-to-connect-via-named-pipe-but-getting-open-basedir-restriction-in)

My configuration (edit):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For mysql 80 you need to enter following named pipe for windows

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '\\.\pipe\MySQL80'
```

you should also check the [phpmyadmn manual for connection](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html) and the [mysql manual for more information on named pipes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-named-pipe.html)

To extent the answer:

The MySQL driver will always try to use sockets(linux) or named pipes(windows), when you add localhost as host, only when it can't use Sockets/named pipes, it will try to connect via TCP/IP, so under normal circumstances you don't need the line i wrote, only if you have a **different name** for the socket/named pipe you need to enter the socket/named pipe at that place.

so if you **don't allow** TCP/IP communnications for MySQL and the named pipe can't be established the connection would fail.

Comment: How can I find out the correct name for `\\.\pipe\MySQL80`? I did not change it manually. `named_pipe_full_access_group` contains `*everyone*`. I documentations says, that `\\.\pipe\MySQL` is the default value. I'm not getting it. Did you try it by your own?

Comment: chekc with pdiplist (cpnsole program) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/pipelist , how your named pipes is called, it can differ

Comment: I added a screenshot of my current configuration to the question. HeidiSQL can still connect. But php or phpMyAdmin cannot.